# Amibiguous operator in reference class?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a class that mimics a reference to some value. To do that I want to define operator overloads so that it behaves appropriately. When I do that, `operator+` resolves correctly, but `operator*` complains with `error: use of overloaded operator '*' is ambiguous (with operand types 'ref<int>' and 'int')` (at least in Clang 3.4).

Here's what I've done (with most things made explicit and removing all of the extra stuff):

```
template <typename T> class ref {
private:
  T &val;

public:
  ref(T &r) : val(r) {}

  template <typename R> ref<T> &operator=(R const &rhs) {
    val = rhs;
    return *this;
  }

  // BINOP_TY(+);
  template <typename L, typename R>
  friend auto operator+(L lhs, ref<R> rhs) -> decltype((lhs) + (rhs.val));

  template <typename L, typename R>
  friend auto operator+(ref<L> lhs, R rhs) -> decltype((lhs.val) + (rhs));

  template <typename L, typename R>
  friend auto operator+(ref<L> lhs, ref<R> rhs)
      -> decltype((lhs.val) + (rhs.val));

  // BINOP_TY(*);
  template <typename L, typename R>
  friend auto operator*(L lhs, ref<R> rhs) -> decltype((lhs) * (rhs.val));

  template <typename L, typename R>
  friend auto operator*(ref<L> lhs, R rhs) -> decltype((lhs.val) * (rhs));

  template <typename L, typename R>
  friend auto operator*(ref<L> lhs, ref<R> rhs)
      -> decltype((lhs.val) * (rhs.val));
};

// BINOP(+);
template <typename L, typename R>
auto operator+(L lhs, ref<R> rhs) -> decltype((lhs) + (rhs.val)) {
  return lhs + rhs.val;
}

template <typename L, typename R>
auto operator+(ref<L> lhs, R rhs) -> decltype((lhs.val) + (rhs)) {
  return lhs.val + rhs;
}

template <typename L, typename R>
auto operator+(ref<L> lhs, ref<R> rhs) -> decltype((lhs.val) + (rhs.val)) {
  return lhs.val + rhs.val;
}

// BINOP(*);
template <typename L, typename R>
auto operator*(L lhs, ref<R> rhs) -> decltype((lhs) * (rhs.val)) {
  return lhs * rhs.val;
}

template <typename L, typename R>
auto operator*(ref<L> lhs, R rhs) -> decltype((lhs.val) * (rhs)) {
  return lhs.val * rhs;
}

template <typename L, typename R>
auto operator*(ref<L> lhs, ref<R> rhs) -> decltype((lhs.val) * (rhs.val)) {
  return lhs.val * rhs.val;
}

// Works.
void plus(ref<int> r, int i) {
  r = r + i;
}

// Fails.
void mult(ref<int> r, int i) {
  r = r * i;
}
```

Full output:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 ref2.cpp
ref2.cpp:75:13: error: use of overloaded operator '*' is ambiguous (with operand types 'ref<int>' and 'int')
      r = r * i;
          ~ ^ ~
ref2.cpp:29:19: note: candidate function [with L = int, R = int]
      friend auto operator*(ref<L> lhs, R rhs) -> decltype((lhs.val) * (rhs));
                  ^
ref2.cpp:59:10: note: candidate function [with L = int, R = int]
    auto operator*(ref<L> lhs, R rhs) -> decltype((lhs.val) * (rhs)) {
         ^
1 error generated.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Both g++ and clang++ compile it fine in my case. Is your code accurate? Any namespaces involved in the real code?

Comment: What if you define your operators right there, in the class, inline at the point of friend declaration (instead of making a separate out-of-class declaration)? Does it solve the problem?

Comment: @AnT What version of clang++? And, yes, that codes fails exactly like that for me.

Comment: I tried it online on Coliru, which uses 4.2.1, and it compiles there. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3365e39eea7b694b

Comment: There is no version 4.2.1 of Clang. Running `clang++ -v` on Coliru gives me 3.6.0 so I suspect this is a bug in Clang 3.4.

Comment: Oh, OK. I didn't know that `-dumpversion` for Clang produces meaningless results.

Comment: Me neither. It appears that `-dumpversion` returned, at some point, the version of GCC it mimicked.